How can I replicate a youtube.com purchase through the dev console?
so I recently wanted to subscribe to YouTube Premium Family Membership in Nigeria. Sadly the option for the family plan wasnt available in the account. Upon creating a second account, I was able to see the family plan pop up.
Now for some reason, the family plan isn't available for account 1, but it's definitely able to subscribe to it (I tried it through IOS App Store and it worked, just more expensive).
Now my question is, am I somehow able to replicate the purchase of a family plan through the console maybe? I need a way to get to the paymentbox to pop up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you have a solution, I will compensate you :)
